# Adium stopped working with pastes from other users

Tags: adium

I see stuff like this now anytime someone changes their font or pastes a link.

```
<im:html xmlns:im='http://jabber.org/protocol/xhtml-im'><xht:body xmlns:xht='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'><xht:p>for example, <xht:a href='http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/office-jerk/id423593206?mt=8'>http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/office-jerk/id423593206?mt=8</xht:a></xht:p></xht:body></im:html>
```

Not sure why it's not being parsed.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

**UPDATE:** Fixed in Adium 1.4.3rc1. See [bug ticket](http://trac.adium.im/ticket/15419).

Comment: I have a 10.6 machine, receiving this stuff from my parents using 10.5
Noticed just yesterday, never seen this before. Quite annoying..

Comment: **Complaining about it on this site won't help.** The Adium guys are aware of the issue and a fix is probably being worked on right now.

Comment: This issue was fixed with a recent update. <3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This appears to an issue with OS X Lion iChat clients sending XHTML-IM formatted messages. In my experience it happens sporadically.

A [ticket](http://trac.adium.im/ticket/15419) has been filed in the Adium issue tracker against it.

Unable to find a fix thus far.

Comment: +1 for link to the bug ticket. This is not limited to Lion iChat; it's happening on IMs sent from other clients as well.

Comment: @JCotton, I'm not following: this is happening to people who USE adium on the receiving side?

Comment: Yes the XML envelope wraps the response received by Adium users. Senders don't notice anything. It's Adium users on the receiving side with at least versions 1.4.2 and 1.4.3b2. It happens on all IMs too, not just links and font changes.

Comment: I am seeing it just from pidgin users.