# Adium Showing Jabber Markup

Tags: macos, adium

My Adium (which I just deleted, redownloaded and reinstalled) has gone mad. My chats are seen as normal on my side, but to the other person, the markup is all seen. So this is what the other person sees:

```
<im:html xmlns:im='http://jabber.org/protocol/xhtml-im'><xht:body xmlns:xht='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'><xht:p><xht:span style='font-family: Lucida Grande; font-size: large;'>new adium. same result?</xht:span></xht:p></xht:body></im:html>
```

What should I do? I haven't changed my Adium options ever.

Comment: Duplicate of [Adium stopped working with pastes from other users](http://superuser.com/questions/324426/adium-stopped-working-with-pastes-from-other-users)

Comment: @grawity I know it looks the same, but it might not be. I'm not pasting or changing fonts or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue in Adium that arose in the last day or so. I believe it was caused by something having changed on Google's side.

http://trac.adium.im/ticket/15419

Judging by the amount of activity on that Trac ticket, I bet this bug will get fixed soon.

Comment: Updating the sending client to the latest Adium beta resolved the problem.